# SQL Oracle: Where <Col Val> == <Item in a list of characters>

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT * 
FROM BIG_ASS_DB
where ID in (PLAN4808,LWVL4813,CPPLTXRS,FRBSTXHJ);
```

The parenthesis contain a list copied from a .txt file.  This is a shortened example. 
The error I get is:

```
ORA-00904: "CHWAHKAH": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 9,739
```

Thanks in advance for your help kind ladies and sirs

Comment: It would help seeing some of the text instead of `item1`, `item2` et cetera. But based on that error, I assume that some of the text you have copied contains characters such as % which is a wildcard operator used in SQL when doing string text comparisons and Oracle is trying to interpret that % as an operator, not actual text? Purely an assumption though. Until I see some data examples, I can't assist further than that.

Comment: I updated the question thanks Jonathon.  There are no "%" anywhere

Comment: @JonathonOgden - you should copy your comment, paste it as an answer, and delete your comment. What you provided is the correct answer.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `ID` column is a text column, you need to surround your list elements with quotation marks `'` like so `'PLAN4808'` as they are text.

Without quotations, SQL is interpreting them as an *identifier* (as the error message states) for a database object (table, column name, function, et cetera) otherwise.